# Neural networks, general inquiry - how mini-batching fits into the big picture?

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, deep-learning, tensorflow, theano

I am graduate student in math, it is my first look at the Deep learning. One of the things that strike me when looking at this material is what seems to be a confusion between implementation details and the big picture or the big principles. This confusion starts right away with a simple feed-forward network "architecture".

Specifically, I now struggle to understand "the proper" context of "mini-batching". There are many online sources on neural networks, but so far I was not able to find, what to me seems, a satisfactory presentation of the material.

Here is the list of questions that I believe will help me to see the mini-batching in it's "natural context".

I am afraid that the questions might be too vague. But I have no other access to an expert in the field, am looking for comments that can point me to my incorrect understanding of the big picture, or incorrect break up of neural network to its "modules" and how mini-batching fits in those "modules".

**Edited later**: Additionally, I believe that someone who has coded or familiar with neural network framework probably has a conceptual view of what are the main moving parts and what is the best way to describe their proper mutual relationships.

---

1. **How is mini-batching represented by a computational graph?** By which I mean that given the "original" computational graph what changes should I make to this graph so that it represents the new computational graph associated with the mini batching?

Here is what I try to picture. Suppose we have a general framework of "computation graph". A framework that supports evaluation of gradients for any function represented as a graph (which is used to encode the neural network and then evaluate gradient for the training phase.) Given such a graph e.g

[image]

which reads:

> [image]

I want to do mini-batching on `x`. Thinking of `x` as the training example, and of the value of `s` (output of the graph) as the loss associated with the training example. `w` is a parameter that I want to learn by running an optimization algorithm of my choice. So to keep things simple, I want my batch to be of size 2. **Is this "new" graph below defines the mini-batching?**

[image]

Here the two training examples are represented by `x1` and `x2` and I have an additional node in the graph that adds all losses `s1` and `s2` together (and perhaps normalized i.e. divided by the batch size).

2. If the above graph is indeed the mini-batching, what I do not understand is **when exactly the efficiency people associate with the mini-batching can be exploited?**.

Specifically, is it true that the biggest contribution is when we have an appropriate hardware that can parallelly process each of the sub-graphs (which on the last graph would be the blue and the black sub-graphs), **if we do not have such a hardware is there any computational benefit to mini-batching?**

3. **Why people "couple" mini-batching with [stochastic gradient descent averaging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_gradient_descent#Averaging)** or (any other optimization algorithms averaging)?

Specifically, given any computational graph, why should optimization algorithm care how the graph was constructed? It seems to me that the way the loss function of the mini-batching is defined (as sum of losses for each sub-graph) gives absolute decoupling between mini-batching and optimization algorithm. If there is benefit for "averaging" over iterations of the optimization algorithms why should this averaging be necessarily coupled with the mini-batch size?

4. Somewhat related to the previous question **why people "couple" mini-batching with gradient evaluation?**

Specifically, If I have a general environment that can evaluate gradients (Jacobians), why does the environment's implementation "cares" which graph it is being fed? I can use general environment and feed it with "the new graph" and ask the environment to find the gradient with respect to `w`, and feed it to my optimization step.

5. **Why is there so much emphasis on the indexing used in the implementation of mini-batching?.**

Specifically, I encounter relatively long explanations on how one can "introduce" additional index to parameters in a feed-forward network, and use it to implement mini-batching. I again do not understand why this coupling is necessary, wouldn't any reasonable way to pass from an original computational graph (the black graph) to a new graph (combined blue+black graph) do the job?

Any comments references to literature are welcome! Thanks

Comment: Have you been to [Neural Networks and Deep Learning](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/) by Michael Nielsen

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on one of the other sites, perhaps **statistics** or **machine learning**.

Comment: @Prune It does belong at another site, if there was only one to choose it would be easy, but with 3 I think only the OP can decide. That is why I did not give it a close vote.

Comment: That's why I gave it a general close vote.  We don't necessarily have to suggest a particular site; the issue is that it doesn't belong *here*.  It's a lovely question, but isn't SO material.

Comment: It is SO material and I could answer it, but the OP stated `But I have no other access to an expert in the field` which is why I pointed out the other three sites. If you ask a [TensorFlow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tensorflow) question, then you do want to be on SO. You have to find where the experts hang out for your interest. Many don't even hang out here but instead on e-mail groups or Google Groups.

Comment: Thanks to your comments, can I migrate the question to CrossValidated?

Comment: @Prune,  I would also say that I think that someone who works with `TensorFlow` or `Theano` can provide insights to my question, it is not purely theoretical. For example how computation on graphs is incorporated in those frameworks and whether there is indeed a separation between such things as mini-batching, computational graph, gradient evaluation and etc...

Comment: Sure, I don't know how, but the way I do it is just to post it as a new one there and delete this one. You have to delete it before it gets an answer, otherwise you can't delete it and start to get down votes.

Comment: The comment was for @Prune and others. I didn't tag it with his name because it wasn't just for him.

Comment: @GuyCoder I have raised a flag to moderators, asking to migrate my question, maybe the moderator can do this? I know that it is definitely possible to migrate from MathStack Exchange to CrossValidation.

Comment: Yes the moderators can, but they are busy enough and do it on their own personal time. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, some notation / recap.

In most supervised machine learning models, we want to minimize $\DeclareMathOperator{\E}{\mathbb E}$
$$
L(f) = \E_{(x, y) \sim P}\left[ \ell(f(x), y) + \lambda J(f) \right]
,$$
where $\ell : \mathcal Y \times \mathcal Y \to \mathbb R$ is a loss function, e.g. $\ell(y, y') = \tfrac12 (y - y')^2$, $J$ is some kind of regularization function that penalizes complexity of the model, and $\lambda$ is a weight trading off between the two.

Since we don't have access to the data distribution $P$, we instead use samples: $$
\hat L(f) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \ell(f(x_i), y_i) + \lambda J(f)
.$$
Typically, we use an optimizer based on gradient information:
$$
\nabla \hat L(f) = \frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n \nabla \ell(f(x_i), y_i) + \lambda \nabla J(f)
.$$

"Minibatching" can be used to refer to two different things:

1. Evaluating $f(x_i)$ and/or $\nabla \ell(f(x_i), y_i)$ for several different $(x_i, y_i)$ pairs at the same time (with the same $f$).
2. Estimating $\hat L$ and $\nabla \hat L$ based on averages over subsamples of the data.

To answer your specific questions:

1. Yes, I think this is right.
2. Yes, it is the case that the biggest advantage in the neural network context is that minibatches can be evaluated on a GPU in almost the same time as a single-point batch would have been. Even on "traditional" CPUs, though, SIMD processing means that some (smaller) level of minibatching is potentially helpful. Note that the size of a minibatch also affects the relative number of function and gradient evaluations, and if those have dramatically different computational costs then the tradeoff can change.
3. You are correct that the gradient averaging does not have to be the same size as the computational averaging (though of course it can't be smaller). If you can only fit your model into GPU memory for 5 inputs at a time, you might decide to e.g. use optimization minibatches of size 50 but compute that in 10 separate passes. People generally don't do this for two reasons: one is that it's much simpler code-wise to do everything at the same time. The other is that, since you'll need to recompute the forward step with your new batch anyway, it takes almost exactly the same amount of time to do an optimization step with 5 inputs followed by another optimization step with 5 inputs as it does to do a single optimization step with 10 inputs computed over two passes, and the former *usually* gets you farther along in the optimization.
4. I'm not sure I understand this question, but typically we need to compute the gradients for specific inputs at a time; TensorFlow or Theano will do all it can in combining gradients at model-building time, but it just gives you some function that needs data to evaluate the actual gradient at that point. We need the average gradient on a batch of data, so we might as well compute it all at once.
5. I don't know what you're talking about here. An example of an explanation that doesn't make sense to you might help here.

Comment: Dougal, many thanks for your answer. I am still wondering about few things and have a few comments: First:  why the "the relative number of function and gradient evaluations" changes? Do you mean by this that the cost might not scale when we  evaluate one gradient of ,say, matrix valued function vs many gradient of vector valued function (one row of a matrix at a time) ?

Comment: Second: For my questions 4,5 what "bothers" me is the following: if the benefits of mini-batching (in the sense of computation efficiency) are 
tight to a specific hardware, shouldn't the implementation of the mini-batching left to the discretion of "hardware expert"? Why then mini-batching is part of the theory? Does it play in a sense that: 
"if you speed up the computation using mini-batching, well then it sort of blends in as SGD averaging and theoretical justification is in place".

Comment: Second continued: In any case are there other major optimization tricks that can be justified theoretically or the mini-batching is the main tool to speed up things?

Comment: Third, related to the third answer:  "..it's much simpler code-wise to do everything at the same time.." just a comment: to me it seems like a bad idea, why  would you want to marry those two concepts? If in the future you would like to separate mini-batching and optimization averages you are stuck, additionally a new person who wants to understand the implementation can get confused by two somewhat different concepts blended together in the implementation - it is harder to analyse.

Comment: Never mind about the function evaluations vs gradient evaluations thing; it's not really relevant to this setting and pretty optimizer-dependent anyway. Second: in general ML usually, and in deep learning nearly always, the "hardware expert" is the same person as the one developing the model. Reasonably efficient implementation is key to these models being at all usable (they frequently take several days to a week to train). Moreover, what you call "SGD averaging" (which I'd just call "minibatching" usually) is meaningful to the optimizer in achieving a good bias-variance tradeoff; it's _not_

Comment: [...] just some computational trick. Code-wise, it's _significantly_ more code to have to store gradients and average them appropriately, for (my guess is) little actual gain. It's possible that it is actually worthwhile and people should be doing it more often – I guess usually people just don't try because they have the same impression as I do, but I don't actually know. If you want to try it and run some experiments, you should. :)

Comment: @Danica what do you mean by **since we dont have access to data distribution , we instead use samples** ? What difference does it make, say if we get access to data distribution in terms of formula?

Comment: @user0193 It depends on what we mean by “knowing $P$.” If we had no computational constraints, then we’d be able to directly minimize the loss of $f$ on $P$ (following the gradient of the integral of the loss), which would avoid any worry about overfitting, since we’d be fitting directly to the distribution we’re trying to perform well on. Or maybe “knowing $P$” means we can sample from it at will, in which case we’d still run SGD but with fresh samples each time, which would also help dramatically in avoiding worrying about overfitting.

Comment: @Danica Ok, so the problem of "knowing or unknowing **P**" is all about overfitting or underfitting problem?

Comment: @user0193 Yes — which is in many ways the core problem of statistics and machine learning. :)